# Voltage gain from the Amplifier input to the load

Tags: voltage, amplifier, gain, homework

[image: Image of the question text]

[image: Schematic]

[image: Image of the solution text]

I don't understand where the solution for part C coming from. What I thought is also *Vo/Vi*. I found Vo as 303 mV and Vi as Vs*(10/10+100). However in solution it seems my thought is wrong. How should I think?

Comment: How did you derive the formula for a voltage divider?

Comment: In point C you need to find the voltage gain from point Vi to Vo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the circuit without the generator (and then the associated resistance). Once you detach the generator you should use a voltage divider using RO and RL to find the output voltage VO dependant on Vi (and so the requested transfer function).